# Application auto-kills when starting new intent activity from SherlockFragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

When i call startActivity inside a SherlockFragment like this

```
Intent browse = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("URL");
startActivity( browse );
```

android default browser starts fine but the main activity of my app is gone (onStop event is called). When i press back to return to SherlockFragment in stack the application re-starts from initial state and not from the last activity fragment state.

Comment: The way the activity manager manage your activity instances (go back top the last, create a new one...) can be customized using flags that you give to your Intent, you should look into that.

Comment: This one for instance is a perfect example : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the android app lifecycle can help you find out whats wrong. When an activity is onPause or onStop and another activity needs too much memory, the paused activity process is killed and when the user goes back it starts all over from the onCreate method, which would explain why you always come back to the initial state. Save data somwhere on the external storage in the onStop and then in onCreate verify if there is data to retrieve. Hope this helps

[(Check out this link to learn more about saving files in android)](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVnSi.png]